# Can not call acpi_call method in ubuntun 12.10

Tags: makefile, nvidia, acpi, ubuntu-12.10, optimus

I have a notebook has a optimus graphic cards(Nvidia). So I want to relax notebook with acpi_call method. But error is given. I had downloaded acpi_call_master from this web page: (https://github.com/mkottman/acpi_call)
Then this zip is exracted by me, and following code is called in terminal by me. However these errors are given:

```
dagli@dagli-Inspiron-N5110:~/acpi_call-master$ ls
acpi_call.c  examples  Makefile  README.md  support
dagli@dagli-Inspiron-N5110:~/acpi_call-master$ sudo make
make -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build M=/home/dagli/acpi_call-master modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok. Durdu.
make: *** [default] Hata 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a kernel module and as such requires the Linux kernel headers to build.  In many cases you should be able to identify the package that would provide that file using `dpkg` such as:

```
dpkg --search /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build
```

You can do the same on the [Ubuntu package site](http://packages.ubuntu.com/).  Though it didn't exactly work, the package you need will be something like `linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic`.  There do appear to be both x86 (32-bit) and x64 options.  See if the following works:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic
```

Remember that you will have to learn how to configure/load kernel modules to make this work.  It is not a standard user program.